# Updating reactjs state with axios object returned from Alphavantage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, axios

I need to pass some stock data to a component named Chart. So far, the Chart component only returns the "test" value placed into state at the top of this code.

Rather than setting state and passing the new data to the Chart component, it gives the error, "TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function".

I think the getTimeSeries function needs to be defined outside of the render method because the function needs to update state. If so, where does it go?

I think I need to .bind(this), or something with binding, somewhere. I'm not sure.

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {
state = {
  currentUser: null,
  instr: null,
  instrData: ['test']
};

constructor(props) {
  super(props)
}

componentDidMount() {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth()
  this.setState({ currentUser, instr: 'NFLX' });
}

render() {
    const { currentUser } = this.state;

    var getTimeSeries = function(instr){
      if(instr!=null){
      const key = 'myKey';
      var url = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=${instr}&apikey=${key}`;
      console.log(url);
        axios.get(url)
          .then((response) => {
            (()=>{ console.log(response.data["Time Series (Daily)"]) })
 // THIS IS NOT UPDATING STATE:
            (()=>{ this.setState({ instrData: response.data["Time Series (Daily)"] }) }) 
            (()=>{ console.log(this.state) })
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
      };
    }; // end getTimeSeries

return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Hi {currentUser && currentUser.email}!
          { getTimeSeries(this.state.instr) }
        </Text>
        <Chart
          instrument={this.state.instr}
          instrData={this.state.instrData}
        />
        <VotingButtons instrument={this.state.instr} />
      </View>
    );//end return
  }// end render
}//end class

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
})
```

[image: Errors]
[image: The Alphavantage data, expanded]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of stuff that's not right here, I'm afraid. Here's a quick runthrough of the big problems:

- You're triggering your axios call inside your `render()` method. A successful axios call will cause state to update (your `setState()` call), which will then cause another `render()` call - React components automatically re-render when their state changes. So you're setting up an infinite loop. Probably less dangerous to do this in the `componentWillMount()` lifecycle method, BUT...
- Trying to store AJAX data in component state like this is a bit of an antipattern in React. It's not really supposed to act as a full-on MVC system, it's more like just a View. If you want to do this sort of thing, I strongly recommend using React alongside a robust state management system - Redux is very good and popular.
- Your axios promise callbacks are all weird and I don't get what you're trying to do.

  ```
  axios.get(url)
        .then((response) => {
  ```

all fine so far, then we get...

```
             (()=>{ console.log(response.data["Time Series (Daily)"]) })
```

OK, this is what's confusing me. What I expect to see here would be just:

```
             console.log(response.data["Time Series (Daily)"]);
```

Instead of doing this, you've declared a function that does it. But you haven't called that function, you've just declared it and left it there. And because you haven't assigned it to anything, it's not really doing much.

```
            // THIS IS NOT UPDATING STATE:
            (()=>{ this.setState({ instrData: response.data["Time Series (Daily)"] }) }) 
            (()=>{ console.log(this.state) })
```

These lines will also do nothing as you're not actually executing `this.setState()` or `console.log()`, you're declaring functions that will execute them:

```
 foo(); //a call to function foo, no args
 () => { foo(); } //a function that calls function foo with no args
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is the feedback I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to Duncan Thacker.

---

Still needs to import the date, but this working code pulls in quotes and builds a candlestick chart:

[Chart.js](https://github.com/Micah81/xcharts-react-webview/blob/master/app/components/Chart.js)

[Api.js](https://github.com/Micah81/xcharts-react-webview/blob/master/app/utils/api.js)